# Convert kick-start motorcycle to electric

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, starting

Objective: Modify Honda S90 '67 so that it starts by switching the key or by pressing a button.

- What's needed?
- What are the downsides?
- Can I still start it using the kick-start in case the battery is dead? Or what does one do in those situations aside from push starting it?

Background: this motorcycle has been previously modified and I've bought it in a fairly bad condition. It was running with a CDI and custom stator. All electrical system has been removed or replaced so I'm doing a a lot of rebuilding. I'm new to the world motorcycles but I've already gained a lot of experience from working with this bike.

Comment: Does the flywheel have teeth for the stater motor to engage with? If not, then you need to solve that, next is where / how you will locate / mount the starter motor.

Comment: Just buy a bike with electric start. It's not worth the custom fabrication work here.

Comment: Solar, Cory, thanks for the feedback! It's certainly proving to be more difficult that I was originally expecting it to be. I'll leave the question open a little longer to see if anyone else pitches in.